# spring.tld tag library attributes differences

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-tld

In many tags of `spring.tld` there are those attributes: `htmlEscape` `javaScriptEscape`

The question may seem trivial, but which is the difference from html escape and javascript escape in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the htmlEscape is use to escape literal within the html document. like for example, if the html document contains special characters, it will be escaped as follows:

```
Original : <    >    "      &
Escaped  : &lt; &gt; &quot; &amp;
```

Javascript escape will apply across javascript literal. Suppose I have the literal:

```
<script>
    function helloWorld(){
        alert('<html:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="hello" />')
    }
<script>
```

Applying a javascript will escape the single and double quotes, the newline chars, the tabs, etc.